# Why are some papers copy-protected?

Tags: publications

Once in a while I stumble over copy-protected files [like this](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/kdd99.pdf). When I try to copy the title "MetaCost: a general method for making classifiers cost-sensitive" I just get garbage:

✁✄✂✆☎✞✝✠✟☛✡☞✂✍✌✠✎
✏✑✁✓✒✔✁✓✕✆☎✗✖✘✁✍✂✆✙✔✟✛✚✢✜✣✟✞✕✤☎✗✥✛✦✧✒✔★✩✝✪✖✫☎✬✡✭✡✭✦✫✮✯✁✓✕✆✡✰✝✠✟☛✡☞✂✲✱☞✳✴✁✓✒✔✡✭✦✵✂✆✦✫✶☛✁

Why do people do that?

Comment: It might not be copy-protected. If you look at the title bar the original file was called copy.dvi, which means that they compiled it with LaTeX (and not with pdfLaTeX for instance). If they didn't pay attention to the workflow, they might have lost the underlying text. Probably this question is better suited to TeX.SE, if asked on a different premise.

Comment: Sure that this is copy protection and not just some sloppy preparation (e.g. bad encoding)? I had a similar thing with a CV.

Comment: I have no problem copying the file to my own computer and then open it. What do you mean by _get garbage_?

Comment: @scaaahu He's referring to copy-pasting the text.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I was aware that it might have been created with TeX, but I thought this was done on purpose. Hm. I'm not sure what to do now. I think I'll just post it in the tex.SE chat and see if they think it could be by accident. If so, moving it to tex.SE would be best (in that case I'd adjust the title to something like "How do PDFs get 'copy-protected'?" - but feel free to suggest a better title.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about academia but TeX

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩: One of the top users of tex.SE thinks it is a deliberate action ([source](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29373084#29373084)), not a mistake. This means it is not about TeX, as I am not asking how to do it.

Comment: It is a TeX issue. See http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~aty/bibliog/latex/LaTeXtoPDF.html

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 Where do you get from that link that it is a TeX issue?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano The font glyphs have not been fully included in the PDF; looks like one of the normal issues with making pdf from latex that I have experience in the past. Not something that should be debated in academia.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 Those are not the font glyphs. The font glyphs are what is shown on the page, not what you get when copying the text.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Academia, but is about PDFs (not necessarily TeX).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano It's missing the glyph-to-character encoding (it uses a non-standard encoding). Not necessarily a TeX issue, but definitely a PDF issue (one that I see fairly often with old PDFs). see e.g. [PDF Font encoding — why can't I copy text from a PDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12703387/) and [If PDF copy+paste gives garbage text — what is wrong with the PDF source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12184304/)

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I doubt it's intended to avoid plagiarism. I see it often in old PDFs, created in an era when small file sizes were important (because this slightly reduces the file size). (One of the SO answers I linked to says: "Distiller produces such files when "Smallest File Size" preset is used.")

Comment: It's easy enough to render the PDF to a high-res image and then OCR it though. Or just type it out. It wouldn't be a barrier against any half-way determined plagiarism.